# I want to receive as a json array instead of a json object in Kotlin retrofit

Tags: kotlin

```
data class LeagueEntryDTO(
    @SerializedName("leagueId") val leagueId : String,
    @SerializedName("summonerId") val summonerId : String,
    @SerializedName("summonerName") val summonerName : String,
    @SerializedName("queueType") val queueType : String,
    @SerializedName("tier") val tier : String,
    @SerializedName("rank") val rank : String,

    @SerializedName("leaguePoints") val leaguePoints : Int,
    @SerializedName("wins") val wins : Int,
    @SerializedName("losses") val losses : Int,

    @SerializedName("hotStreak") val hotStreak : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("veteran") val veteran : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("freshBlood") val freshBlood : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("inactive") val inactive : Boolean,

    @SerializedName("miniSeries") val miniSeries : MiniSeriesDTO

)
```

```
private fun searchLeagueEntryByEncryptedSummonerId(id: String){
     
        lolAPI.getSummonerEntriesByEncryptedSummonerID(id, API_KEY)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LeagueEntryDTO>{
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LeagueEntryDTO>,
                    response: Response<LeagueEntryDTO>
                ) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful.not()){
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "${response.code()}")
                        return
                    }
                    response.body()?.let {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", it.toString())
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "${response.code()}")
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LeagueEntryDTO>, t: Throwable) {
             
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "${call.request().url()}")
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "${t.cause}")
                    call.request().body().let {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "${it.toString()}")
                    }
                }

            })
    }
```

```
@GET("/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/{encryptedSummonerId}")
    fun getSummonerEntriesByEncryptedSummonerID(
        @Path("encryptedSummonerId") encryptedSummonerId : String,
        @Query("api_key") APIKey : String
    ): Call<LeagueEntryDTO>
```

data to receive

```
[
    {
        "leagueId": "e04db760-931c-475f-88b8-b94979f013da",
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "rank": "III",
        "summonerId": "fhXsvqx4tjuqt7JWGeTMUuMihXlqNwDIsPHEWwc3urIBtCc",
        "summonerName": "do skip leg day",
        "leaguePoints": 23,
        "wins": 62,
        "losses": 72,
        "veteran": false,
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "hotStreak": false
    }
]
```

But the format of the data I am receiving in my code

```
 {
        "leagueId": "e04db760-931c-475f-88b8-b94979f013da",
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "tier": "GOLD",
        "rank": "III",
        "summonerId": "fhXsvqx4tjuqt7JWGeTMUuMihXlqNwDIsPHEWwc3urIBtCc",
        "summonerName": "do skip leg day",
        "leaguePoints": 23,
        "wins": 62,
        "losses": 72,
        "veteran": false,
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "hotStreak": false
    }
```

error caused by it

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

How to solve this problem?

I am trying to use Retrofit using Riot Open API.
Help

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0):

So you should be expecting to receive `List<LeagueEntryDTO>`

Replace  `Call<LeagueEntryDTO>` with  `Call<List<LeagueEntryDTO>>`, as well in other places